# cons* in scheme - how to implement

Tags: scheme

I tried to implement the cons* (https://scheme.com/tspl4/objects.html#./objects:s44).

Examples:

```
(cons* '()) -> ()
(cons* '(a b)) -> (a b)
(cons* 'a 'b 'c) -> (a b . c)
(cons* 'a 'b '(c d)) -> (a b c d)
```

this is what I did do far but I don't know how to replace the ?? to make the third example (the dot notion) work

```
   (define cons*
  (lambda x
    (if
     (null? x)
     x
     (if (list? (car (reverse x)))
         (fold-right cons (car (reverse x)) (reverse (cdr (reverse x))))
         ???
      )
     )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a lo-fi way using `lambda` -

```scm
(define cons*
  (lambda l
    (cond ((null? l) null)
          ((null? (cdr l)) (car l))
          (else (cons (car l) (apply cons* (cdr l)))))))
```

Here's a way you can do it using [match](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._match%29%29) (Racket)

```scm
(define (cons* . l)
  (match l
    ((list) null)                                ; empty list
    ((list a) a)                                 ; singleton list
    ((list a b ...) (cons a (apply cons* b)))))  ; two or elements
```

Often times patterns and order can be rearranged and still produce correct programs. It all depends on how you're thinking about the problem -

```scm
(define (cons* . l)
  (match l
    ((list a) a)                                ; one element
    ((list a b) (cons a b))                     ; two elements
    ((list a b ...) (cons a (apply cons* b))))) ; more
```

Or sugar it up with [define/match](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._define%2Fmatch%29%29) -

```scm
(define/match (cons* . l)
  [((list)) null]
  [((list a)) a]
  [((list a b ...)) (cons a (apply cons* b))])
```

All four variants produce the expected output -

```scm
(cons* '())
(cons* '(a b))
(cons* 'a 'b 'c)
(cons* 'a 'b '(c d))
```

```scm
'()
'(a b)
'(a b . c)
'(a b c d)
```

Comment: It looks like these solutions with `match` and `define/match` are using Racket, but OP tagged the question [tag:scheme]. "_This to me suggests `cons*` should always return a `cons`...._"[Note that R6RS Scheme already has the library function `cons*`.](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-4.html#node_idx_240) When called on a single argument, it simply returns that argument.

Comment: @adabsurdum thanks for the review. I added a lo-fi `lambda` variant for Scheme. thanks for the link about `cons*` called with a single non-list item. it's a strange interface indeed! I removed that section to avoid confusing other readers.

Comment: I just noticed `(cond ((null? l) null)`  -->  `(cond ((null? l) l)`. Also, this version returns: `(cons*)`  -->  `()`, where the R6RS library errors when no arguments are provided.

Answer (score 0):

### A Simple Procedure

I think that you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. It seems best not to use `lambda x` here, since that would allow calls like `(cons*)` with no arguments. Instead, I would use `(x . xs)`, and I would even just use the `define` syntax:

```
(define (cons* x . xs)
  (if (null? xs)
      x
      (cons x (apply cons*
                     (car xs)
                     (cdr xs)))))
```

If there is only one argument to `cons*`, then `xs` is empty, i.e., `(null? xs)` is true, and that single argument `x` should be returned. Otherwise you should `cons` the first argument to the result of calling `cons*` again, with the first element of `xs` as the first argument, followed by the remaining arguments from `xs`. The trick here is that `(cdr xs)` returns a list, which will itself be put into a list thanks to the `(x . xs)` syntax. This is the reason for using `apply`, which will apply `cons*` to the arguments in the list.

This works for all of the test cases:

```
> (cons* '())
()
> (cons* '(a b))
(a b)
> (cons* 'a 'b 'c)
(a b . c)
> (cons* 'a 'b '(c d))
(a b c d)
```

---

### Using Mutation

Taking a closer look at what a proper list really is suggests another approach to solving the problem. Consider a list like `(a b c d)`. This is really a chain of cons cells that look like this:

```
(a . (b . (c . (d . ()))))
```

We would like to transform this list to an improper, or dotted, list:

```
(a . (b . (c . (d . ()))))  -->  (a . (b . (c . d)))
```

This transformed list is equivalent to `(abc.d)`, which is what we would like the call to `(cons* 'a 'b 'c 'd)` to return.

We could mutate the proper list to an improper list by setting the `cdr` of the next-to-last pair to the `car` of the last pair; that is, by setting the `cdr` of `(c . (d .())` to `d`. We can use the `list-tail` procedure to get at the next-to-last pair, `list-ref` to get at the `car` of the last pair, and `set-cdr!` to set the `cdr` of the next-to-last pair to the new value. After this, the list is no longer terminated by an empty list (unless the `car` of the final pair is itself an empty list!).

Here is a procedure `proper->improper!` that mutates a proper list to an improper list. Note that the input must be a proper list to avoid an error. If the input list contains only a single element, then that element is simply returned and no mutation takes place.

```
(define (proper->improper! xs)
  (cond ((null? (cdr xs))
         (car xs))
        (else
         (set-cdr! (list-tail xs (- (length xs) 2))
                   (list-ref xs (- (length xs) 1)))
         xs)))
```

Now `cons*` can be defined simply in terms of `proper->improper!`:

```
(define (cons* . xs)
  (proper->improper! xs))
```

Here, the arguments to `cons*` are packed up into a fresh list and passed to `proper->improper!` which effectively removes the terminal empty list from its input, returning a chain of pairs whose last `cdr` is the last argument to `cons*`; or if only one argument is provided, that argument is returned. This works just like the other solution:

```
> (cons* '())
()
> (cons* 'a)
a
> (cons* 'a 'b 'c 'd)
(a b c . d)
> (cons* 'a 'b '(c d))
(a b c d)
```

---

### Real Life

In real life, at least in Chez Scheme, `cons*` is not implemented like any of these solutions, or even in Scheme at all. Instead Chez opted to make [`cons*` a primitive procedure](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme/blob/master/s/prims.ss), implemented in C (I believe).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use a macro instead of a function to transform a `cons*` into a series of `cons` calls:

```lisp
(define-syntax cons*
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ arg) arg)
    ((_ arg1 rest ...) (cons arg1 (cons* rest ...)))))

(define (writeln x)
  (write x)
  (newline))

(writeln (cons* '())) ;; -> '()
(writeln (cons* '(a b))) ;; -> '(a b)
(writeln (cons* 'a 'b 'c)) ;; -> (cons 'a (cons 'b 'c)) -> '(a b . c)
(writeln (cons* 'a 'b '(c d))) ;; -> (cons 'a (cons 'b '(c d))) -> '(a b c d)
```

Comment: can you add explanation why the macro would be better in this case?

Comment: Using a macro here is pretty questionable, because you can't `apply` it now. What if I have a list, and I wish to expand its last element in place? `(apply cons* xs)` would work if `cons*` were implemented as a function (as it should be), but is impossible with a macro.